# Using Java to extract embedded ZIP from DOC file

Tags: java, ole

I have a DOC file with multiple embedded files.  There are PDFs, DOCs, and ZIPs embedded within this file.  I have used Apache POI to drill through the POIFS.  I can extract the OLE10 file information, original filenames, paths, sizes, etc.

Where I am getting stuck, is during the extraction of the ZIP files from the document.  I've used a DocumentInputStream to copy to a FileOutputStream with IOUtils.

```
// Load the file object and embedded file system
        File file = new File(filePathBuilder.toString());
        POIFSFileSystem wordDocFS = new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream(file));
        DirectoryNode docRootDir = wordDocFS.getRoot();

        // Read ROOT POIFS
        Iterator<Entry> docRootDirIter = docRootDir.getEntries();
        while(docRootDirIter.hasNext()){
            Entry docRootDirEntry = docRootDirIter.next();

            if (docRootDirEntry.getName().contains("ObjectPool")){
                objPoolDir = (DirectoryNode) docRootDirEntry;

                // Read ObjectPool POIFS directory ---> ObjectPool is location of embedded files within a DOC file
                Iterator<Entry> objPoolDirIter = objPoolDir.getEntries();
                while(objPoolDirIter.hasNext()){
                    Entry objPoolDirEntry = objPoolDirIter.next();

                    // Read ObjectPool POIFS subdirectories
                    if(objPoolDirEntry.isDirectoryEntry()){
                        DirectoryNode objPoolSubDir = (DirectoryNode) objPoolDirEntry;

                        Iterator<Entry> objPoolSubDirIter = objPoolSubDir.getEntries();
                        while (objPoolSubDirIter.hasNext()){
                            Entry objPoolSubDirEntry = objPoolSubDirIter.next();

                            // Read embedded OLE10 files, create an OLE object, and read into an ArrayList of OLE objects
                            if (objPoolSubDirEntry.isDocumentEntry()){
                                DocumentEntry objPoolSubDirFile = (DocumentEntry) objPoolSubDirEntry;

                                if((objPoolSubDirFile.getSize() < 15_000_000)
                                        && (objPoolSubDirFile.getName().contains("Ole10Native"))){

                                    Ole10Native oleEntry = Ole10Native.createFromEmbeddedOleObject(objPoolSubDir);
                                    OleEntry oleObject = new OleEntry();
                                    String oleFqdn = oleEntry.getFileName();

                                    //System.out.println(oleFqdn+"\t"+oleFqdn.endsWith("zip"));
                                    int oleSize = oleEntry.getDataSize();
                                    String olePath = oleFqdn.substring(
                                            0,
                                            oleFqdn.lastIndexOf("\\")+1
                                    );
                                    String oleFilename = oleFqdn.substring(
                                            oleFqdn.lastIndexOf("\\")+1
                                    );
                                    String oleFileType = oleFqdn.substring(
                                            oleFqdn.lastIndexOf(".")+1
                                    );

                                    oleObject.setFileFQDN(oleFqdn);
                                    oleObject.setFilePath(olePath);
                                    oleObject.setFileName(oleFilename);
                                    oleObject.setFileExtension(oleFileType);
                                    oleObject.setFileSize(oleSize);

                                    if(oleObject.getFileName().contains("game_report")){
                                        String streamFileName = "C:\\Users\\ra069466\\Documents\\Software_Projects\\Maint_Tool_test_files\\testOLE\\"
                                                +oleObject.getFileName();

                                        InputStream inStream = new DocumentInputStream(objPoolSubDirFile);
                                        OutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(streamFileName);
                                        IOUtils.copy(inStream,outStream);

                                        System.out.println("Wrote out: "
                                                +streamFileName);
                                    }
                                    oleEntryList.add(oleObject);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

It appears to copy, but my OS doesn't recognize the ZIP file as an archive.

[image]

I've tried setting my IOUtils.copy() to output a ZipOutputStream, and still no success.  I receive a  "java.util.zip.ZipException: no current ZIP entry".  I'm totally out of ideas how I can extract the ZIP file and write it out as a ZIP archive I can open.

Comment: Have you looked at the extracted file with a hex editor to see if you can identify the problem?  The first two characters should be PK

Comment: No, I haven't.  I have tried: 
`ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(streamFileName));
System.out.println("Zip Entry: "+zipInputStream.getNextEntry());` and get NULL

If I run 
`ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(streamFileName);
 Stream inputStream = zipFile.stream();
 System.out.println("Zip Entry: "+inputStream.count());`
I get 34....which is correct

Comment: @NormR, "PK" is missing in the embedded ZIP file.  Which is weird because I can save it out of the Word DOC and open it locally.  So, it looks like IOUtils.copy(inStream,outStream); was working correctly and I need to read the stream and then save as a zip.

Comment: Can you compare the first few bytes of the bad zip file against a good zip file to see what else is different?  For example are the first bytes all 0s or are they clear text like from a .txt file?

Comment: @NormR, here's what the ZIP starts with :  `¿†“  game_report 71_42.zip C:\prism\sys-bin- `.  That's the file I make a copy of.  When I use 7zip to look at the embedded OLE, it reads the same.  So, the copy command is DEFINITELY working.  The problem lies with the "PK"  missing from the embedded ZIP file.  All the embedded ZIPs within the Word DOC are missing "PK".

Comment: @NormR, I stand corrected....I did a search within the ZIP file, and "PK" is indicated at character 255, not at character 0.

Comment: All my zip files start with "PK".  Why don't the zip files that your code extracts from the doc start with PK?

Comment: I think I got it!!  I created an InputStream of the OLE DocumentInputStream.  Then skipped the first 255 characters and started writing out the file as a FileOutputStream using the IOUtilsCopy.  NOW, I can read the file as a ZipInputStream!  When I reanalyzed the embedded ZIP file, it appears the first 255 characters is some sort of executable instructions to write the ZIP to the user's TMP directory.

Answer (score 0):

@NormR, thanks for the help!  Removing the extra characters by InputStream.skip() prior to the first PK record solved the issue.  I'm able to extract the embedded ZIP files out of the Word DOC and write them locally.  And, I'm now able to extract the ZipEntries from the ZipFiles to be properly processed.